# different colors in cells as value increases

Tags: colors, openoffice-calc, cells

The conditional formatting that I am using right now is .. if cell equals 1 then this color  .. if cell equals 2 then this color and so on.

Is there a way I can format it for more than just the 3 colors since there is only 3 conditional lines?

I am using openoffice calc.

Answer (score 0):

More than 3 colors in OpenOffice requires some clever formula writing.  Details are in this OpenOffice forum thread: [Re: Is it possible to count by color?](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=19129&p=88553#p88492)

LibreOffice supports more than 3 colors through the conditional formatting GUI, so switching to LibreOffice is an option as well.